# Listing deeply nested sub-entities in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model that contains a number of nested collections.  For example...

```
My Sales Record
  Contains a collection of Customers
    Each Customer contains a collection of Orders
      Each Order contains a collection of Items
```

I would like to be able to create a list of all the Items associated with the Sales Record without resulting to writing nested foreach loops.  I have tried...

```
var items = SalesRecord.SelectMany(r => r.Customers)
               .SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
               .Select(o => o.Items);
```

but this doesn't work.

Is this achievable in LINQ?

Comment: `SelectMany` won't show results until you actually loop trough the resultset. Are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more SelectMany needed:

```
var items = SalesRecord.Customers // simply select customers from record
               .SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
               .SelectMany(o => o.Items); // here
```

You need to flatten results, otherwise you will have collection of items collections. Also if you need a list of items, don't forget to call `ToList()` at the end of query.

Comment: That's just all of the items, unassociated with any sales record

Comment: @Servy there's only one sales record in this context: `SalesRecord`.

Comment: @Servy exactly, thats all items of sales record

Comment: @TimS. No, there's not.  If there was only one he couldn't call `SelectMany` on it.  `SalesRecord` should really be named `SalesRecords`.

Comment: @Servy His text description "My Sales Record" and property name, `SalesRecord`, suggest singular, while his code that "doesn't work" suggests plural. I'm guessing it's actually singular, but you're right that the `SelectMany` implies otherwise, and I didn't notice that until you pointed it out.

Comment: Actually if OP has single record, then neither Select nor SelectMany will not work. He should simply access Customers property instead

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Unless of course he *doesn't* have a singular record, but a collection of records.  There is conflicting evidence suggesting both options.

Comment: This worked for me.  Sales record does indeed have a collection of Customers, but I think it was the statement SalesRecord.SelectMany(r => r.Customers) that caused one of the problems in my initial code.  I had tried, I'd thought, just about every combination of .Select(), .SelectMany() but had obviously missed the logical answer in my confusion.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select` to map each sales record into an item that contains that record as well as a flattened list of items for that record, using several calls to `SelectMany`:

```
var items = SalesRecord.Select(record => new
{
    record,
    Items = record.Customers
        .SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
        .SelectMany(o => o.Items),
});
```

Comment: Should be `record.Customers`

Comment: @TimS. Indeed it should.

Comment: @TimS. Copy paste is really getting to me today.  It was right in an earlier revision.  Thanks.